# xml node exists using variables in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I am trying to determine if a Mailbox with a certain DisplayName exists in my powershell script (see example xml below). I can find the node if I hard-code the value, but I have not been able to pass this value as a parameter. I have tried various ways of escaping, using single quotes and double, but none of it is going the right way.

The ultimate goal is to create the Mailbox node if one doesn't exist with the same DisplayName. There may be 0 or more Mailbox nodes.

Here's a sample xml:

```
<Profiler>
  <Mailboxes>
    <Mailbox>
      <DisplayName>django</DisplayName>
    </Mailbox>
  </Mailboxes>
</Profiler>
```

This is the piece of code, I want executed if the node doesn't exist:

```
$newMailbox = $xmlData.CreateElement("Mailbox")
$newDisplayName = $xmlData.CreateElement("DisplayName")
$newDisplayNameText = $xmlData.CreateTextNode($mailboxName)
$newDisplayName.AppendChild($newDisplayNameText)
$newMailbox.AppendChild($newDisplayName)
$mailboxes = $xmlData.SelectSingleNode("./Profiler/Mailboxes")
$mailboxes.AppendChild($newMailbox)
```

This piece of code works:

```
$users = $xmlData.SelectNodes("./Profiler/Mailboxes/Mailbox/DisplayName[text() = 'django']")
write-host $users.count
```

> output from script: 1

This doesn't:

```
$mailboxName = "django"
$users = $xmlData.SelectNodes("./Profiler/Mailboxes/Mailbox/DisplayName[text() = $mailboxName]")
write-host $users.count
```

> output from script: 0

I also tried this:

```
$mailboxName = "django"
$users= $xmlData.SelectNodes("./Profiler/Mailboxes/Mailbox[DisplayName = $mailbox]")
```

> output from script: Exception calling "SelectNodes" with "1" argument(s): "Expression must evaluate to a node-set."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `$users = $xmlData.SelectNodes("./Profiler/Mailboxes/Mailbox/DisplayName[. = '$mailbox']")`.

Comment: According to http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html and from what I've seen, it won't work - anything inside a single-quoted string won't be evaluated. And if I try double quotes, I get new errors

Comment: In my understanding the powershell string in my code samples is delimited by double quotes so powershell will do variable interpolation. The single quotes are inside the double quoted string, and they are in their for XPath, so that the argument passed to `SelectNodes` will be the string `./Profiler/Mailboxes/Mailbox/DisplayName[. = 'jango']` and not the string `./Profiler/Mailboxes/Mailbox/DisplayName[. = jango]` as the latter would compare `DisplayName` to an XML element named `jango` and not the string value `jango`.